# Using TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync got an error: The specified account does not exist

Tags: uwp, windows-store

I get an error when updating UWP APP using TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync: The specified account does not exist

I try to upgrade according to the sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#download-and-install-package-updates-silently), while using StoreQueueItem.StatusChanged to obtain progress information, **sometimes** I get this status information (using personal hotspots will be more prone to this phenomenon):

```
 {
     "ExtendedError":null,
     "PackageInstallExtendedState":14,
     "PackageInstallState":4,
     "UpdateStatus":{
         "PackageFamilyName":"AppName",
         "PackageDownloadSizeInBytes":2260223,
         "PackageBytesDownloaded":2260223,
         "PackageDownloadProgress":0.95,
         "TotalDownloadProgress":0.95,
         "PackageUpdateState":3
     }
 }
```

It looks like Paused, but why Paused? Do I need to call TrySilentDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync again to install?

At the same time I see some error logs in the event viewer (Applications and Services->Microsoft-?Windows->Store->Operational):

> 1. Source: Store-SDK, Event ID: 2004, Task Category: In-App
>    Purchase, Detail:
>    SendStoreRequestWithUris( nullptr,UriHelperV7::InternalStoreEndpointExtensionUrls,
>    UriHelperV7::InternalStoreEndpointExtensionUrlsIds::GetUserCollectionForProducts,
>    cv, jsonCollectionsParameters.Get(), nullptr,
>    collectionsJsonString.GetAddressOf()) Error: `The specified account does not exist`. Function:
>    Windows::Services::Store::Internal::StoreContextServer::GetProductsByKinds
>    Source: \storecontextserver.cpp (4460)

> 2. Source: Store-SDK, Event ID: 2004, Task Category: In-App Purchase, Detail:
>    ChkHr(hrGoldenTicket) Error: `The specified account does not exist`. Function:
>    Windows::Services::Store::Internal::StoreContextServer::SendStoreRequestWithUris
>    Source: \storecontextserver.cpp (4065)

> 3. Source: Install-Service, Event ID: 2008, Task Category:
>    Service, Detail:
>    [Error] ResumeWithFlagsQueueItemId = {9369AD17-2AA2-42A8-8F76-335AFAB88741}
>    Error: The operation completed successfully. Function: InstallQueue2::ResumeWithFlags Source:
>    onecoreuap\enduser\winstore\installservice\libqueue2\installqueue2.cpp
>    (432)

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: I've replied to you on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7445d98f-3498-43e1-9674-987465410822/using-trysilentdownloadandinstallstorepackageupdatesasync-got-an-error-the-specified-account-does?forum=wpsubmit). Please check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The root cause is that I used test flight. The official version does not have this problem. This problem only appears in the test flight version.